# Высота TextField XCode

Tags: objective-c

Помогите пожалуйста решить такую проблему. Есть элемент TextField:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
```

Как задать высоту именно этого элемента(txtName), при помощи кода C-Objective?

Comment: вообще-то правильней бы п писать Objective-C

Comment: @zhenyab, забавно видеть, что с разницей в 13 секунд мы написали одно и то же.

Comment: да, действительно забавно :)

Comment: У меня под ответом кончились комментарии. Если не боитесь, можете постучаться в скайп (он в профиле у меня), - так будет точно быстрее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Где-то в вашем view controller...
CGRect txtNameFrame = self.txtName.frame;
txtNameFrame.size.height = ВЫСОТА;
self.txtName.frame = txtNameFrame;
```

P.S. Проблема решилась, данный код заработал после того, как спрашивающий подключил Text Field к ViewController-у: нужно было просто связать Text Field из xib-файла с декларацией

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
```

посредством Referencing outlet.

Comment: Кстати пишите всё-таки Objective-C - вас прекрасно поймут, не надо C-Objective)

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, а ваш код не работает (. Я сделал событием на кнопку - остальные события(для теста placeholder) работают на "ОК", а ваше не отрабатывает.

Comment: Ну так и напишите, что именно не срабатывает. Какая ошибка-то?

Comment: Если что, вы можете выложить свой тестовый проект в zip-формате куда-нибудь в инет, и добавить ссылку на него в свой вопрос. Так будет понятнее, о чем у вас там не получается ;)

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, нет конкретного "Failed" или "Warning", просто при нажатии ничего не происходит, хотя другой код для проверки жизни события отрабатывает.

Comment: Очевидно, что вы подцепили к вашему view controller событие и оно отрабатывается, но подключен ли у вас к контроллеру ваш txtName? Добавьте перед моим кодом 

    NSLog(@"Text frame: %@", self.txtName);

И пришлите сюда в комментарии результат вывода.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, смотрите:
2013-09-12 22:03:07.060 ConnectToDB[6537:c07] Text frame: <UITextField: 0x7559a10; frame = (0 0; 169 2); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7560100>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7559bb0>>